# Why does enabling write caching on a disk drive sometimes requires restarting Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I wonder why enabling write caching on a disk drive sometimes requires restarting Microsoft Windows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: well, because its a driver level concept. Some drivers load and unload on the fly (usermode drivers for USB devices for instance) but others can only be loaded while the kernel is booting. thats why it appears to vary between devices.

Comment: @FrankThomas is right.  The other possible scenario is where the drive is currently in use by some process.  Changing the caching setting requires a driver/hdd reset, which Windows won't allow if a process is using the drive -- instead you get asked to restart.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome to copy the comment into an answer.

Comment: Yeah, right, removing the drive and the plugging it in again can't reset the driver even though it *IS* a per-drive setting…

Sheesh.